# Will a bigger engine help cutting performance

Tags: john-deere, lawnmower

I have a 2021 John Deere z355e with a 22hp B&S engine.

I’m wanting to buy the 27hp v twin B&S engine, and I want to know if it will increase the cutting power as my zero turn for better cutting in taller grass?.

seems to run the deck off the revs to the wheels and cutting deck and not separately if that makes sense lol. The engine would fit perfectly just unsure if it will allow me to do more commercial mowing by giving better performance/Torque to the deck.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! More HP can never hurt ... that is as long as the other parts can take the abuse. If the deck isn't built to handle the extra power, you're going to kill it rather quickly, I'd think. That also goes for the transmission. Your initial assumption of having a bigger engine should allow it to cut through more grass easier. You just have to weigh the pro's and con's of it, though.

Comment: Properly sharpened and set blades is the first step, you could have 50hp and still get a poor cut.

Comment: You could spend a lot of time, effort and money to upgrade the engine for minimal gain. I'm with @SolarMike on this, you're better off sharpening first to see if that gets you where you want to be. I got a Dremel attachment for that and it made a huge difference with very minimal work.

Answer (score 1):

The makers of the lawn mower will have designed the blades to run at a specific tip speed.  As you will know, the mower is designed to be driven at max throttle to run at the chosen blade tip speed.

Since HP = TORQUE X REVS, you need to identify whether the bigger engine is getting its increased HP from a higher torque or higher Revs.   You will need more torque, not more revs.

With higher torque the machine should be able to drive up steeper slopes and not slow down in thicker grass (not sure if longer grass is relevant since it has a maximum height for the cutters).

Whether the belt drive to the wheels and blades is capable of handling the extra torque is something you may just need to experience, or even ask the manufacturer.